# How to share folders using NFS?

Tags: nfs

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=249889

In the above link it is shown that I need to do

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server nfs-common portmap
```

However a software called portmap doesnot exist in ubuntu 12.04

How exactly do I configure NFS in ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: I recently used this on both 12.04 and 12.10 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That article is over 6 years old and shouldn't be followed. You can set up NFS sharing by following the documentation here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

Comment: did it using Ubuntu 12.04 documentation. Thanks for the help. NFS is really the fastest way to transfer data.